# How can I use the current value of a foreach loop to alter the width of the drawn object?

Tags: tikz-pgf, scaling, unit-of-measure

I'd like to create a Ti*k*z plot where a vector of numbers is used to include a picture. I want the picture to be scaled using the current value, so that the pictures higher on the `y-axis` are larger than those at low values.
Somehow I always get the error *"Illegal unit of measurement (pt inserted)"* when trying to use my variable in the width argument. That's what I've done so far:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \y [count=\x] in {0.5, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 0.95, 1, 1.05, 1.07, 1.2, 1.205, 2, 3, 3.1, 5, 5.4, 5.8, 6.1, 6.15, 6.125, 6.4}
\node at(\x,\y) {\includegraphics[width=\y*0.2cm]{../figs/Potato.png}};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\includegraphics` does, unlike pgf, not parse the arguments of its keys, so you need to parse.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \y [count=\x] in {0.5, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 0.95, 1, 1.05, 1.07, 1.2, 1.205, 2, 3, 3.1, 5, 5.4, 5.8, 6.1, 6.15, 6.125, 6.4}
\node at(\x,\y) {\pgfmathparse{\y*0.2}\includegraphics[width=\pgfmathresult cm]{example-image-duck}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

BTW, `\x` and `\y` also get used by the `calc` library. So I personally would perhaps use

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \Y [count=\X] in {0.5, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 0.95, 1, 1.05, 1.07, 1.2, 1.205, 2, 3, 3.1, 5, 5.4, 5.8, 6.1, 6.15, 6.125, 6.4}
\node at(\X,\Y) {\pgfmathparse{\Y*0.2}\includegraphics[width=\pgfmathresult cm]{example-image-duck}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

to be on the safe side if I later decide to use `calc` in the loop.

Comment: My answer explains why the error occurs, and avoids to introduce a new macro (in particular a macro that has a meaning in some packages).

Answer (score 3):

It's possible to advance the calculations on `foreach` loop and avoid `\pgfmathparse`

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \y [count=\x, evaluate=\y as \width using \y*0.2] in {0.5, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 0.95, 1, 1.05, 1.07, 1.2, 1.205, 2, 3, 3.1, 5, 5.4, 5.8, 6.1, 6.15, 6.125, 6.4}
\node at(\x,\y) {\includegraphics[width=\width cm]{example-image}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Well, this introduces a new macro, and also makes sure that \includegraphics does not have to parse what you feed it with, like my answer.